# Haskell getsizeof big integer

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get the size in bytes of a big integer, given that there's arbitrary precision math under the hood, and I'd like to know how much space the result is actually using.

Here's a sample:

```
Prelude> import Data.Bits
Prelude> let fac1000 = product [1..1000] # big!
Prelude Data.Bits> finiteBitSize fac1000

<interactive>:37:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘b0’ arising from a use of ‘finiteBitSize’
      prevents the constraint ‘(FiniteBits b0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘b0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance FiniteBits Bool -- Defined in ‘Data.Bits’
        instance FiniteBits Int -- Defined in ‘Data.Bits’
        instance FiniteBits Word -- Defined in ‘Data.Bits’
    • In the expression: finiteBitSize fac1000
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = finiteBitSize fac1000

<interactive>:37:15: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘b0’ arising from a use of ‘fac1000’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num b0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘b0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘finiteBitSize’, namely ‘fac1000’
      In the expression: finiteBitSize fac1000
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = finiteBitSize fac1000
```

The type annotations they are suggesting do not seem reasonable, when I coerce to an integer for example:

```
Prelude Data.Bits> finiteBitSize (fac1000 :: Int)
64
```

Well, that's a big number and I don't believe it.  In python, I get:

```
>>> import sys, math
>>> sys.getsizeof(math.factorial(1000))
1164
```

which looks a lot more credible to me for the astronomically large 4.02e2568.

Comment: What happens if you do `(finiteBitSize fac1000) :: Int`? That's what GHC is actually suggesting, your version is casting the huge number to an `Int` so it's not surprising it becomes much smaller than you expect.

Comment: Correction: I just looked up the function. I misunderstood, it always returns an `Int`, and the ambiguity is in its argument. But when you coerce it to an `Int` then you'll certainly get something too small. And `Integer` doesn't seem to be an instance of `FiniteBits`, for obvious reasons.

Comment: From the docs: "Return the number of bits in the type of the argument. The actual value of the argument is ignored." Hence, `finiteBitSize` does not care about the value of the argument, but only about its type. That's not what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may approximate the number of bytes by asking for its log base 256 using the [integer-logarithms](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-logarithms-1.0.3/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Logarithms.html#v:integerLogBase) package:

```
Math.NumberTheory.Logarithms> integerLogBase 256 (product [1..1000])
1066
```

This is only an approximation because it accounts only for the bytes being used to store the number; typically arbitrary-precision integers also have some overhead for storing information about the length of the number and probably a bit of over-allocation, and neither of these will be accounted for by taking the logarithm.

If you don't mind getting the approximate size reported in bits instead of bytes, `integerLog2` will be faster.

```
Math.NumberTheory.Logarithms> integerLog2 (product [1..1000])
8529
```

If you want the true answer, you'll have to touch some really low-level APIs and depend on the exact [definition of `Integer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-gmp-1.0.2.0/docs/GHC-Integer-GMP-Internals.html#t:Integer):

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
import Data.Bits
import GHC.Exts
import GHC.Integer.GMP.Internals
import GHC.Prim

sizeOfInteger :: Integer -> Int
sizeOfInteger n = constructorSize + case n of
    S# i -> finiteBitSize (I# i) `div` 8
    Jp# bn -> sizeOfBigNat bn
    Jn# bn -> sizeOfBigNat bn
    where
    constructorSize = finiteBitSize (0 :: Word) `div` 8
    sizeOfBigNat (BN# arr) = constructorSize + I# (sizeofByteArray# arr)
```

Try it out in ghci:

```
> sizeOfInteger (product [1..1000])
1088
```

Beware! I don't know all the promises of these internal APIs. It's possible that computing equal `Integer`s in different ways may produce values that are represented differently. When touching these internal APIs you sometimes lose the guarantees of the abstract external API; in this case, you may not have that `x == y` implies `sizeOfInteger x == sizeOfInteger y`. Read the docs carefully if you plan to take this route!

Comment: What is the unit here?  `finiteBitSize` gives a size in bits and at least one haddock-doc source says `sizeofByteArray` gives a size in bytes.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thanks, fixed!

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson And thanks a second time! Yikes.

Comment: One thing to point out -- in `sizeOfBigNat`, there isn't actually an extra constructor, as the `data BigNat = BN# ByteArray#` is unpacked into the `data Integer`.  However, there is a word for the length of the `ByteArray#` in `BigNat` that isn't otherwise accounted for, so I think the code still gives the right answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.  Any chance you have a link explaining the `#` syntax?  I have never encountered this before. This is magichash and the reason is to unbox the types?  I'm going off this: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/02/primitive-haskell

Comment: @Mittenchops The [manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=magichash#extension-MagicHash) is the definitive source for its meaning.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielWagner.  I have read this section, and while I see statements like `The hash sign does not change semantics at all. We tend to use variable names ending in “#” for unboxed values or types (e.g. Int#), but there is no requirement to do so; they are just plain ordinary variables.` that suggest to me this changes nothing and is just a naming convention, it /looks/ like this is actually providing some kind of pointer semantics.  Is the latter true?

Comment: @Mittenchops The statement "this changes nothing and is just a naming convention" is correct. I don't know what "this is actually providing some kind of pointer semantics" means to you, so I can't comment on whether that is correct, but I suspect it is not.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielWagner.  I guess my question is: am I to understand that this code works identically if MagicHash is not used and I replace instances of `Jp#` with `Jp` and `I#` with `I`, etc?  This is just a naming convention you chose that has no semantic impact on the code?

Comment: @Mittenchops I didn't choose it. And you would have to turn off MagicHash in the module that defines `Integer` and make those replacements there, too. But yes, if you replaced all occurrences of `Jp#` with `Jp`, etc., it would work exactly the same way.

Comment: It seems kind of inconvenient they named the variable such that the magichash pragma is required to use functions defined in the library, but this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You've misunderstood what [`finiteBitSize`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:finiteBitSize) does.  From the docs, emphasis mine:

> Return the number of bits in the type of the argument. *The actual value of the argument is ignored.*

The `finiteBitSize :: FiniteBits b => b -> Int` function tells you a property of the *type* `b`, and it uses the argument to pick out which type.  Any `Int` would give you the same answer:

```
ghci> finiteBitSize (0 :: Int)
64
ghci> finiteBitSize (maxBound :: Int)
64
ghci> finiteBitSize (undefined :: Int)
64
```

This is because `Int` is the type of lazy *machine* integers, which fit in one word.  Indeed:

```
ghci> product [1..1000] :: Int
0
```

A bit smaller than you may have been expecting :-)

If you want to measure the size of `product [1..1000]` as an unbounded `Integer`, you'll need a different technique.  [Daniel Wagner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56333518/237428) provides two good approaches, both mathematical (how to compute log<sub>2</sub> 100!) and GHC-internal.